# Counting number of times the remote phone rings

Tags: android, call, telephony, telephonymanager

In my Android app, while calling a remote phone I need to keep track of the number of times the remote phone rings before it (i.e. remote phone) goes to off-hook or idle state. Googling for this topic hasn't yielded anything of much help. A brute force method could be to process the audio and count the rings -- but this seems ugly and avoidable and may not work with all carriers/phones. I'm looking for a pointer to some documented/undocumented API that Android may have to address this requirement.

Any suggestions for solution or pointers to where shall I explore will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
B.Sodhi

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SIP protocol!

If you go deep enough in your Android you can have a callback, when the remote phone is received the call signal. From there you will count X seconds and is done.

Not so easy to implement as it said, but is possible. A technical man, never says it is imposible :)